# DETACH DELETE Neo4j 2.3.x/Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, memgraphdb, opencypher

What is the behaviour and purpose of the new Cypher operator `DETACH DELETE` added in Neo4j 2.3.x?

Comment: If you are coming here from a search engine to try to find the difference between `detach` and `delete`: `detach` removes the relationships of a node. `delete` deletes a node. You will need to `detach` a node before you `delete` it if it has any relationships.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to delete nodes, you need to delete the relationships as well.  In previous versions you would need to do:

```
MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
DELETE n, r
```

Now you can simply say:

```
MATCH (n)
DETACH DELETE n
```

Answer (score 6):

I could not comment on Brian's answer so here it is:

This command:

```
MATCH n
DETACH DELETE n
```

Gives to following error:

```
WARNING: Parentheses are required to identify nodes in patterns, i.e. (n) (line 1, column 7 (offset: 6))
"MATCH n"
       ^
```

Thus the correct command is:

```
MATCH (n)
DETACH DELETE n
```